# Is it possible to infer generic types recursively in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Take this code, for example:

```ts
const [divEl, spanEl] = createElements([
    ['div', { id: 'test' }, [
        ['a', { href: 'test' }, [
            ['img', { src: 'test' }, null]
        ]],
        ['img', { href: 'test' }, null]
    ]],
    ['span', null, null]
]);
```

I want TypeScript to infer the type of `divEl` to be `HTMLDivElement` and the type of `spanEl` to be `HTMLSpanElement`. And I also want it to check the given attributes and show errors based on the inferred type (for example, it should show an error on `['img', { href: 'test' }, null]`, because `HTMLImageElement` doesn't have an `href` property).

After some research, this is what I have so far:

```ts
type ElementTag = keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap;

type ElementAttributes<T extends ElementTag> = {
    [K in keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]]?: Partial<HTMLElementTagNameMap[T][K]> | null;
};

type ElementArray<T extends ElementTag> = [
    T,
    ElementAttributes<T> | null,
    ElementArray<ElementTag>[] | string | null
];

type MappedElementArray<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ElementArray<infer L> ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[L] : never;
};

// This is the signature for the createElements function.
type CreateElements = <T extends ElementArray<ElementTag>[] | []>(
    array: T
) => MappedElementArray<T>;
```

I'd have to change `ElementArray<ElementTag>[]` to something generic, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is this even possible?

I know it's possible to do it manually, but `T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, ...` isn't pretty.

Comment: This sounds like it may require [Variadric Tuples](https://fettblog.eu/variadic-tuple-types-preview/) to be released in Typescript 4.0.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't figured out how to apply that to this problem yet, but thanks, I'll spend some time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Partial answer)

TypeScript doesn't like recursive types. You can mostly work around this, so long as you don't require inference... however, since that's required here, I don't think it is possible to get TS to take the last step.

You can have one of the following features:

1. Infer the return type to be a tuple with the correct return types.
2. Deeply typecheck the passed array

The first is easy. We just need `T` in `createElements` to extend a discriminated union. You had this already, but this is a slightly different way of looking at it.

```
type DiscriminatedElements = {
    // you can, of course, do better than unknown here.
    [K in keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]: readonly [K, Partial<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]> | null, unknown]
}[keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]

type ToElementTypes<T extends readonly DiscriminatedElements[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends [keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap, any, any] ? HTMLElementTagNameMap[T[K][0]] : never
}

declare const createElements: <T extends readonly DiscriminatedElements[] | []>(
    array: T
) => ToElementTypes<T>

createElements([
    ['span', {}, null]
]) // [HTMLSpanElement]
```

The second is a bit trickier. As I said before, TS doesn't like recursive types. See [GH#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980). That said, we can work around it to create a type of an arbitrary depth for checking... but if we try to combine this type with any inference, TS will realize it is potentially infinite.

```
type DiscriminatedElements = {
    [K in keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]: readonly [K, Partial<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]> | null]
}[keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap]

type NumberLine = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
type CreateElementArray<T extends readonly [any, any], N extends number> = T extends readonly [infer A, infer B] ? {
    done: readonly [A, B, null],
    recurse: readonly [A, B, null | readonly CreateElementArray<DiscriminatedElements, NumberLine[N]>[]]
}[N extends 0 ? 'done' : 'recurse'] : never

// Increase up N and NumberLine as required
type ElementItem = CreateElementArray<DiscriminatedElements, 4>

declare const createElements: (
    array: readonly ElementItem[]
) => HTMLElement[];


const [divEl, spanEl] = createElements([
    ['div', { id: 'test' }, [
        ['a', { href: 'test' }, [
            ['img', { src: 'test' }, null]
        ]],
        ['img', { href: 'test' }, null] // error, as expected
    ]],
    ['span', null, null]
]);
```

I don't think variadic tuples help you here. They will be an awesome addition to the language, but don't solve the problem that you are trying to model here.

A solution that would let you keep the best of both worlds would be to accept HTML elements as the third item in the tuple, and simply call `createElements` within that array.

Comment: That second one is great, thank you! I think I can benefit more from it, since I guess I can just do `as [HTMLDivElement, HTMLSpanElement]` to get the correct return types. I had thought about calling `createElements` within the array, but I prefer the simple array structure.